# How to statically enforce that a generic type has a particular representation?

Tags: generics, rust, memory-alignment

I have a generic `struct Foo<T>` that I want to use for FFI. For example, the following could be used for a memory mapping implementation.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use memmap::MmapMut;

#[repr(C)]
struct Shared<T> {
    foo: MmapMut,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

I want this to be FFI safe, so I'd like to enforce that `T` *also* has to be `repr(C)`. The issue is that representations aren't traits in Rust, and therefore I don't see a straightforward way of enforcing this statically, something like `struct Foo<T: ReprC>` would be nice, but as far as I can tell does not exist. Could a macro be used?

Comment: @samcarter I am so confused, why are you commenting here on my beamer question? :P

Comment: Ah, I appreciate it! I think that'll work! Thanks @samcarter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a trait, `ReprC`, and use it as a trait bound for your methods. It's not enforcement of what really matters but it may be better than documentation.